# Pandas index title in line with column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For my dataset I want to replace the automatic index with the first column in the dataframe and set the new index title inline with all the column names of the dataframe.

Original dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]),columns=['a','b','c'])
df

  a b c 
0 1 2 3
1 4 5 6
```

Set the index as the first column:

```
df.set_index('a',inplace=True)
df

  b c
a 
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

However, now I am stuck on how to get the index title inline with the column headers. Below is the output I am looking for:

```
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this trick, but I think it is not best practice:

```
df.columns.name = df.index.name
df.index.name = None
print (df)
a  b  c
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

Comment: Hmm for me this just deletes the index column header

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
print(df.reset_index().to_string(index=False))
```

For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]),columns=['a','b','c'])
df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
df

   b  c
a      
1  2  3
4  5  6

print(df.reset_index().to_string(index=False))
 a  b  c
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the following instruction:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Did you try to test your solution on the data provided in the question? This is the opposite of what was asked for, as the question is about converting a column into an index, not the other way around.